# Open bottom sheet dialog only for one time

Tags: android, dialog, fragment

I have an issue with my Bottom Sheet Dialog. How do make my bottom sheet dialog only open for one time? If I clicked the button twice from my activity, it will open up the dialog twice. How to check whether the dialog is open or not from the activity? If the dialog is open, it will dismiss if I click the button. Here's my code to open the fragment from the activity. Thanks

```
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("outletData", new Gson().toJson(outletData));

            BookOutletDialogFragment bookOutletDialogFragment = BookOutletDialogFragment.newInstance();
            bookOutletDialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            bookOutletDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), bookOutletDialogFragment.TAG);
```

Comment: disable that button when user click on it once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the flag in your Activity as:-

```
    public static boolean isFragmentShown=false;
```

modify your onPause() and onStart() method of your fragments as:-

```
  @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
       Log.e( "Fragment is visible", "Fragment is visible");
       **YouActivityName**.isFragmentShown = true;
    }

@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.e("Fragment is not visible", "Fragment is not visible");
        **YouActivityName**.isFragmentShown = false;
    }
```

And in your click method add this code in your top to check fragment is visible or not:-

```
        if(!isFragmentShown){
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("outletData", new Gson().toJson(outletData));

        BookOutletDialogFragment bookOutletDialogFragment = BookOutletDialogFragment.newInstance();
        bookOutletDialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        bookOutletDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), 
        bookOutletDialogFragment.TAG);}
```

Answer (score 0):

While [Afzal Khan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60372007/9977583)  is true in my case onPause() method never called after doing something (ex: Pressing button) inside Bottom Sheet Dialog. So I just overrided onDismiss() method as I observed that onDismiss() method is called everytime when you dismiss dialog unlike onPause()

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    System.out.println("onDismiss() method called");
     **YouActivityName**.isFragmentShown = false;
}
```